# how to raise utility of an individual having min utility function

Tags: microeconomics, utility

I was doing an exercise of utility and got confused with a min utility function. endowments can redistribute among individuals. How am i supposed to increase his utility. Can i simply reduce the endowment of this min utility person(or give him extra)?

Comment: Can you please be more specific regarding the utility function and what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Given a utility function of the form $U(a,b)=min\{a,b\}$. Suppose that currently $a<b$. To increase utility, you should allocate more of $a$ to this person until $a=b$ and then increase $a,b$ proportionally.

Comment: You should allocate more of $a$ you mean.